# How to improve sense of timing in motion graphics

Tags: after-effects, motion

I would simply ask a way to get a better "sense of timing" in motion graphics... It's not about a software specific question: do you know a good online course that teaches motion graphics fundamentals, regardless you have to work with after effects or a 3d software?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_basic_principles_of_animation

Comment: As a good exercise, try doing something to a music track (think Merrie Melodies). The sense of rhythm and dynamics can be a cheat sheet for which action should happen next.

Answer (score 2):

You could begin by reading or watching videos about the "[12 Principles of Animation](http://minyos.its.rmit.edu.au/aim/a_notes/anim_principles.html)", which are usually cited as a set of rules or building blocks for life-like animations and aren't in any way software-specific. Examples of videos can be found [here](https://vimeo.com/87095612), or [here](https://vimeo.com/93206523).

Answer (score 2):

The book "The Illusion of Life" [amazon link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Illusion-Life-Animation-Editions/dp/0786860707) is also really good for thinking about animation timings, from a stop-motion perspective.  Much of it is highly relevant to motion graphics, and it's a beautiful book.  There are some scanned PDFs of it in the darker corners of the internet, but buying the book is worth it.

If you're thinking more about timings of text for readability in motion graphics, I find one of the best ways is to show your work to a few people who haven't seen it yet, and then ask them which bits they missed.  I find it's often tempting to cram too much into a text-heavy motion graphic.  Judging timings by re-watching it yourself becomes tricky because your eye-brain combination already knows what's coming next.